# Starting headless chrome via protractor fails in docker

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, protractor

We have our end2end tests written in node/protractor and like to execute them inside docker. Unfortunately, this fails as it seems chrome crashes immediately after starting.

This is the log of the `docker run` process

```
Google Chrome 89.0.4389.114
Webdriver-manager has started - give her some time
[11:54:09] I/config_source - curl -o/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[11:54:09] I/config_source - curl -o/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
[11:54:10] I/config_source - curl -o/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[11:54:11] I/start - java -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.29.0 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_89.0.4389.23 -jar /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444
[11:54:11] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 26
Enough of that - lets start the tests

> protractor-cucumber-tests@2.1.0 e2eTests /e2e
> node ./config/e2eNodeRunner.js "-c" "....." "-u" "https://......" "-t" "@smokeTest"

Protractor config file has been created with the following data:
┌────────────┬──────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ Selenium   │ Url                          │ Feature                           │ Tags                         │
├────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ http://12… │ https://…                    │ /                                 │ @smokeTest                   │
└────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
[11:54:39] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:54:39] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[11:54:41] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}),platform=Linux 5.8.0-48-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 789 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '905345c52948', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.8.0-48-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_275'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[11:54:41] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}),platform=Linux 5.8.0-48-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 789 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '905345c52948', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.8.0-48-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_275'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at /e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (/e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (/e2e/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/e2e/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at /e2e/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (/e2e/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at /e2e/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/e2e/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[11:54:41] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

The question I have is, has anyone already faced this problem ? Can anyone understand, why chrome is crushing immediately ?

The capabilities that are used are

```
11:54:40.018 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "chromeOptions": {
    "args": [
      "--headless",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      "--no-sandbox"
    ],
    "perfLoggingPrefs": {
      "enableNetwork": true,
      "enablePage": true,
      "traceCategories": "blink.console,devtools.timeline,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline,toplevel,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline.frame,benchmark"
    }
  },
  "count": 1,
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
    "w3c": false,
    "prefs": {
      "download": {
        "prompt_for_download": false,
        "directory_upgrade": true,
        "default_directory": "\u002fe2e\u002ftests\u002fdownloads"
      }
    }
  },
  "host": "https:\u002f\u002f....,
  "idleTimeout": 300,
  "loggingPrefs": {
    "performance": "ALL"
  },
  "maxDuration": "10800",
  "maxInstances": 1,
  "password": "Test_1234",
  "screenResolution": "1920x1080",
  "shardTestFiles": false,
  "specs": "..\u002ftests\u002ffeatures\u002f**\u002f*.feature",
  "timeZone": "UTC",
  "user": "test_user",
  "version": ""
}
```

and the dockerfile that is used is:

```
FROM node:12.18.3
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    openjdk-8-jre-headless
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
COPY . e2e
RUN cp e2e/runner.sh . ; chmod +x runner.sh
RUN cd e2e ; chmod 744 * ; npm install
RUN npm install -g protractor
RUN npm install -g eslint
RUN webdriver-manager update
ENTRYPOINT ["./runner.sh"]
```

the `runner.sh` script contains basically only `npm run` command with corresponding arguments.

Does anyone already see any problem/error in the scripts or can point me to anything which is related to this ?

Oh yea, we use protractor 7.0.0

Thanks

Comment: I had this problem, and decided to run tests in regular browser session with UI. Let me know, if this is acceptable for you, I'll share some tricks and secrets.

Comment: we have our tests run normally in a regular browser session with UI, where they work as expected. So I would need a solution that works in a headless docker env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that there was a condition part in the protractor configuration file that overwrite my `headless` option :( so a stupid problem.